Implement razorpay payment with custom ui and not with webview swift
i want to implement razorpay payment with my custom ui such as i want to get card deatils from user and want to make payment with that details. Right now it is opening razorpay default webview.
if any way is there please tell.
i try to add payment method and card details in prefill.
internal func showPaymentForm(){
        
        if let brandData = MyVariables.brandData {
            
            razorpay = RazorpayCheckout.initWithKey(brandData.appConfig.razorpay.key, andDelegateWithData: self)
            
            print("PHONE NUMB = \(self.userPhone) , EMAIL ID = \(self.userEmail) , PGORDERID = \(self.pgOrderId)")
            let options: [String:Any] = [
                "amount": "\(self.billTotal * 100)", //This is in currency subunits. 100 = 100 paise= INR 1.
                "currency": "INR",//We support more that 92 international currencies.
                "description": "Demoing Charges",
                "order_id": self.pgOrderId,
                "image": "",
                "name": “name”,
                "prefill": [
                    "contact": self.userPhone,
                    "email": self.userEmail
                ],
                "theme": [
                    "color": "#326E36"
                ],
                "retry": [
                    "enabled": false
                ]
            ]
            razorpay.open(options)
                       
        }

    }

